# Virtual reality world entered by touching a door handle

Tags: story-identification, books

I think this is a longer work. It must be >15 years old. In the universe of the story, virtual reality is a commodity technology and is obvious virtual reality in use on commodity systems. But the protagonist is taken(?) to some sort of corporation(?) building where they are immersed in virtual reality just by touching something – I think it's a door handle.

They enter VR without realising it. This is used to show that the corporation is extremely technically powerful. I think that they realise at a later time that, by touching a door handle, they have entered an advanced VR simulation that they are unable to distinguish from the real environment.

I am trying to find this story as I am researching boundary interfaces for virtual reality systems.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Is this a short story or a longer work?  What distinguishes the VR from the real world?  Can the protagonist leave as simply, or are they trapped?  Also, when and where did you read this?

Comment: In (some versions of) _The Restaurant At The End Of The Universe_, you later find out that when Zaphod entered Zarniwoop's office, he [entered an artificial universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/156928/in-the-radio-series-how-did-zaphod-get-into-the-artificial-universe).

Comment: I think this is a longer work. It must be >15 years old. In the universe of the story, virtual reality is a commodity technology and is obvious virtual reality in use on commodity systems. But the protagonist is taken(?) to some sort of corporation(?) building where they are immersed in virtual reality just by touching something - I think its a door handle. They can't tell this virtual reality is not reality, it is used to show that the corporation is extremely technically powerful.

Comment: Thanks, I will re-read The Restaurant At The End Of The Universe. That is not the example I am thinking of, but it might serve a useful purpose in something I am writing about how people enter and exit virtual reality systems.

Comment: I remember something where a character grabs a handle to open the door and it feels like the handle squirms as it senses and adjusts to the person who is opening the door and then when they open the door the room is customized for them based on the sensing of the handle. I really can’t recall what that’s from though. Oh wait, it’s either Continuing Time or Sprawl Trilogy. The character is about to talk to one of the richest people in the solar system and they have this unique setup where the handle brings you into a VR holosuite like zoom session.

Comment: @ToddWilcox had it; it's from _Count Zero_, when Marly is being interviewed by Virek (page 12 in the paperback edition).

Comment: @ProfVR - If you can no longer log in with the account you used to post this question, please merge your new account with the previous one by following the instructions provided [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). That way, the site will recognise you as the author of the question, and you'll regain the ability to  post comments beneath the question, edit it without approval from other users, and mark an answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) if one is posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prompted by @ToddWilcox: In *Count Zero*, Marly (the disgraced art expert POV character) is interviewed by a billionaire, Virek, "via a sensory link" (page 12):

> "Fraulein Krushkhova," A young man in a technician's dark green smock
> stood in the doorway opposite the one through which she'd entered. "In
> a moment, please, you will cross the room and step through this door.
> Please grasp the knob slowly, firmly, and in a manner that affords
> maximum contact with the flesh of your palm. Step through carefully.
> There should be a minimum of spatial disorientation."
>
> She blinked at him. "I beg–"
>
> "The sensory link," he said, and withdrew, the door closing behind
> him.

[...]

> As her fingers closed around the cool brass knob, it seemed
> to squirm, sliding along a touch spectrum of texture and temperature
> in the first second of contact.
>
> Then it became metal again, green-painted iron, sweeping out and down,
> along a line of perspective, an old railing she grasped now in wonder.

Comment: Thanks. This is almost certainly part of the answer. I read Count Zero shortly after it came out and the door knob is almost certainly the device I was thinking of. It is extremely useful for my research, so thanks.     However, I must be conflating it with a different story. In that other story, the protagonist doesn't realise they have gone into a simulation, and it is only when they think back, they realise that the doorway was the "entrance". I think the door handle itself is a red herring unfortunately.